# Proper XML formatting when viewing log file contents

Tags: xml, linux, vim

I am trying to read some logs through a Linux terminal which contain some XML, (the entire log is not XML, but some of it's contents is).  Is there any text editors, add-ons or scripts which will attempt to format the the contents that is XML to make it easier to read.  I dont need it to save the new formatting, just display it for easy reading.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In vim, you can filter [parts of] your file through any external command.  In this case you can try `xmllint --format`.

Comment: This works. I've had this mapping for ages :nnoremap <leader>xb :%!xmllint --format -<cr> . it could just as easily be an autocommand

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for,  the XML is inside some of the log entries, each line in the log starts with a time stamp.   So xmllint always chokes on the first line because it expects a '<'...

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this pretty print script for vim:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2130